# Tor public key Provided object is too large

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, linux, private-key

I try to import Tor browser public key like this

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290
```

but I get error

```
pubring.kbx': Provided object is too large
```

I use debian based distributive. How I can import public key ? Or where I can download Tor public key *.asc so I can

```
gpg --import tor-key.asc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by [key spam](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/400) - a few days ago this key took up about 30 MB and took about 10 minutes to *delete.* [Suggested mitigation](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f#mitigations).